# how to implement scrollToEnd function in scroll View react native

Tags: react-native, scrollview

Im trying to use scroll to end function from scrollView docs,
but I don't know how to implement it.

right now I get errors: cant find variable scrollToEnd

my code for the scroll view:

```
<ScrollView onContentSizeChange={() => scrollToEnd({ duration: 500 })} style={styles.viewcontainer}>
```

and inside the scrollView i have content that grawing when button clicked.
I want that the view always go to the bottom.

how i implement the scrollToEnd method?

Comment: `scrollToEnd()` is part of the scrollview. So you would need a ref to it. See: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref. You can then call `refName.current.scrollToEnd()`.

Comment: ok so now i declare :  const scrollRef = useRef(null);
and inside scrollview: onContentSizeChange={() => scrollRef.current.scrollToEnd({ duration: 500 })}
you can help me with the continue?....

now i get null is not object

Comment: have you call `ref={scrollRef}` to set ref for the scrollRef? If not try this and retry again with you code. You need set scrollRef with ref ScrollView to use method on ScrollView